# Is possible to create a symlink for a remote file?

Tags: linux

I'm developing an application that reads from /dev/ttyusb0 on remote raspberry. Is possible to create a symlink to the remote device (raspy) on my local development machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Symlinks only point to a *path* – the symlink resolution process essentially just replaces a part of the original name. For example, if you had a path `/home/mario/docs/notes.txt` and `docs` was a symlink to `../luigi/documents`, the process would give you `/home/mario/../luigi/documents/notes.txt`.

Therefore you can only create symlinks for something that **already has** a local path. (For regular files this could be a path provided by a network filesystem such as NFS/SMB/AFS/9p, but devices usually cannot be exported this way.)

---

If your program only reads & writes data but doesn't use any parameters specific to serial ports (flow control, etc.) then you could create an adhoc tunnel using `socat` or `ser2net` on the remote device to link its serial port to a TCP connection, and the opposite on your local machine to link that TCP connection to a "pty".

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624653/create-a-virtual-serial-port-connection-over-tcp
- https://serverfault.com/questions/360321/forwarding-linux-terminal-from-serial-port-to-tcp-with-socat

But you should implement an alternative mechanism in your application itself – in addition to local devices, it should support e.g. RFC2217 over TCP/IP, which is a common "serial over TCP" protocol.